# Open new project in WebStorm IDE from existing folder via terminal

Tags: linux, ide, webstorm

Is it possible to open WebStorm IDE with new project via terminal.

I want to create new folder and then launch IDE as new project with this folder as root.

Comment: Nope -- you have to create project root folder yourself. But yes -- just pass the full path to WebStorm executable (`webstorm` or (older name) `wstorm`) as a parameter -- IDE will either open existing project there (if it find the `.idea` subfolder) or will create new project for that folder.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne, That's what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create project root folder yourself.

Then -- just pass the full path to WebStorm executable (`webstorm` or (older name) `wstorm`) as a parameter -- IDE will either open existing project there (if it find the `.idea` subfolder) or will create new project for that folder:

```
webstorm /path/to/the/project/
```

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/opening-files-from-command-line.html

**P.S.**
If `webstorm` command is not recognized -- use `Tools | Create Command Line Launcher...` to create such alias/command.